# Where in the code are eosio.prods permission set

Tags: nodeos, eosio-code, block-producer, permissions

where can I find the code in which `eosio.prods` permission are set?
I couldn't find it in `system_contract` or `producer_plugin`.

thx for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

ok found it is in the eos folder: `libraries->chain->controller.cpp` line 1985